# Wix Windows 8 Launch Condition

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am working on a Wix installer to support Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8 and higher. I can successfully verify Windows 7 with Service Pack 1, however my windows 8 launch condition continually fails. My stripped back condition for windows 8 is,

```
<bal:Condition Message="Windows 8 or higher supported...."><![CDATA[Installed OR VersionNT >= 602]]></bal:Condition>
```

**Log Entry**

```
[0638:0D20][2015-08-28T07:47:17]i001: Burn v3.9.1208.0, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0)
[0638:0D20][2015-08-28T07:47:18]i052: Condition 'Installed OR VersionNT >= 602' evaluates to false.
```

Am i using the wrong syntax for windows8 or wrong versionNt code?

Answer (score 1):

The condition must evaluate to true for the install to proceed, so it's not clear why you have Installed as part of the condition. What does Installed refer to in your sample?

Also, you are using the wrong syntax for VersionNT. You're using the Windows Installer format, but Burn uses a different format:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html

It may also matter if you don't use the right property (VersionNT64 instead).

Comment: The Installed keyword is a Windows Installer property to ensure the condition is only checked when the user is installing the application and not removing or repairing, as per documentation here, http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/block_install_on_os.html

Comment: I understand the Installed property - I wasn't sure why you were using it in a Bundle, which you seem to be, with the bal extension, and note that your link refers to the Windows Installer Installed property which is not what you are using.

Comment: So I am trying to use a Windows Installer property in my bundle which is incorrect? It would also seem that the format of my VersionNT variable used in Burn is incorrect as it differs from the MSI property VersionNT. I have updated my launch condition as below, which seems to work. <bal:Condition Message="App is only supported on Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, or higher. Please update then rerun this installer.">
      <![CDATA[((VersionNT = v6.1) AND (ServicePackLevel >= 1)) OR VersionNT > v6.1]]>
    </bal:Condition>

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the version numbering used by Burn bundles is a different format to the MSI ([Wix documentation here)](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html).

> **VersionNT** - version value representing the OS version. The result is a
> version variable (v#.#.#.#) which differs from the MSI Property
> 'VersionNT' which is an integer. For example, to use this variable in
> a Bundle condition try: "VersionNT > v6.1".

> **VersionNT64** - version
> value representing the OS version if 64-bit. Undefined if running a
> 32-bit operating system. The result is a version variable (v#.#.#.#)
> which differs from the MSI Property 'VersionNT64' which is an integer.
> For example, to use this variable in a Bundle condition try:
> "VersionNT64 > v6.1".

The values required for Burn bundle are listed here ([Windows Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/sysinfo/operating-system-version))

| Operating system | Version number |
| --- | --- |
| Windows 11 | 10.0* |
| Windows 10 | 10.0* |
| Windows Server 2022 | 10.0* |
| Windows Server 2019 | 10.0* |
| Windows Server 2016 | 10.0* |
| Windows 8.1 | 6.3* |
| Windows Server 2012 R2 | 6.3* |
| Windows 8 | 6.2 |
| Windows Server 2012 | 6.2 |
| Windows 7 | 6.1 |
| Windows Server 2008 R2 | 6.1 |
| Windows Server 2008 | 6.0 |
| Windows Vista | 6.0 |
| Windows Server 2003 R2 | 5.2 |
| Windows Server 2003 | 5.2 |
| Windows XP 64-Bit Edition | 5.2 |
| Windows XP | 5.1 |
| Windows 2000 | 5.0 |

Example usage:

```
<!-- Check OS is Win7 (6.1) or Win8.1 (v6.3) or higher - 32bit and 64bit checks -->
<bal:Condition Message="Required OS is Win7, 8.1 or higher">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR (VersionNT = v6.1) OR (VersionNT >= v6.3) OR (VersionNT64 = v6.1) OR (VersionNT64 >= v6.3)]]>
</bal:Condition>
```